# POST method returning 400 bad request after adding a new param to the RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, postman

I added a new object parameter to the RequestBody of POST method. Below is the syntax of the method at controller.

```
public void registerTask(@RequestBody MyRequestDto myRequestDto)

updated MyRequestDto class:
private final String existing1;
private final String existing2;
private final NewParam myNewparam; // this is the new param that is added
```

the initialization is done through constructor:

```
public MyRequestDto(String existing1, String existing2, NewParam myNewparam){
this.existing1 = existing1;
this.existing2 = existing2;
this.myNewparam = myNewparam;
}
```

This is the new Param class definition:

```
public class NewParam {
    private final String name;

    public NewParam(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

The issue is when I send the tests through postman by adding this NewParam, I get 400 bad request. Following are the scenarios and the result:

1. When the NewParam is not added to the request body. result- 201 is returned
2. When the NewParam is added , but the value is set as null. result - 201 is returned.
   example:

   {
   "existing1": "test1",
   "existing2": "test2",
   "myNewparam": null
   }
3. When the NewParam is added, and initialized to some value. result- 400 Bad Request(The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax)
   example:

   {
   "existing1": "test1",
   "existing2": "test2",
   "myNewparam": {
   "name": "theme"
   }
   }

Note: the integration tests are also failing. While debugging the integration tests, the control is not going to controller, and only getting error as 400 Bad request.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: The setup looks correct. Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. a github-repository?

Comment: Check if your NewParam class is serializable.

Comment: The issue was resolved after added @JsonProperty to the name parameter of the class NewParam. Seems , if there is one variable with name "name", with only parameterized constructor, then Jackson has issues deserializing that object.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions here

1. You can use `@JsonProperty` to give "name" attribute to your class "NewParam" as well as field "name"

for e.g.

```
MyRequestDto class:
@JsonProperty("myNewParam")
private final NewParam newParam;
```

and

```
public class NewParam {
@JsonProperty("newName")
private final String name;
}
```

So when you send request from your postman like below, it should work

```
{ "existing1": "test1", "existing2": "test2", "myNewParam": { "newName": "theme" } }
```

2. Second solution is send name exactly as same as you define class and its fields